# How to loop through series of addresses in a text file and get individual fields in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a text file with multiple addresses in the following format:

335 Ahan St.
Haines City, US 30721

786 Birchmount Dr.
Waterloo, IA 52001

How can I loop through these lines and get individual fields like Street number, street name, city, state, postal code in Node.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const parseAddressFile = path => {
  const data = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path)
  });
  
  data.on('line', (line)=> {
    var address1= line.split(" ")[0];
    
    console.log(address1)
  })
};
```

I'm using readline module and I'm basically stuck after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this using `Regular Expression` with named groups as long as you have addresses in the above mentioned format.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const parseAddressFile = path => {
  const data = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path)
  });

  let address = {};
  const addressList = [];
  data.on('line', (line) => {
    if (line) {
      const temp = line.match(/^((?<streetNumber>\d+) (?<streetName>.+)|(?<city>.+), (?<state>[A-Z]+) (?<postalCode>\d{5,5}))$/);
      address = Object.keys(temp.groups).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (temp.groups[key]) {
          acc[key] = temp.groups[key];
        }
        return acc;
      }, address || {});
    } else {
      addressList.push(address);
      address = null;
    }
  }).on('close', function(line) {
    if (address) {
      addressList.push(address);
    }
    console.log(addressList);
  });
};

parseAddressFile('adress.txt')
```

And the output will be

```
[
  {
    streetName: 'Ahan St.',
    streetNumber: '335',
    city: 'Haines City',
    postalCode: '30721',
    state: 'US'
  },
  {
    streetName: 'Birchmount Dr.',
    streetNumber: '786',
    city: 'Waterloo',
    postalCode: '52001',
    state: 'IA'
  }
]
```

Comment: The above code is quite good.  But the regular expression fails if streetName doesn't end in a '.'  I was able to get it to work by changing:     address = Object.keys(temp.groups).reduce((acc, key) =>  {     to     if (temp) { address = Object.keys(temp.groups).reduce((acc, key) => {    and removing '\.' from the end of     (?<streetName>.+\.)

Comment: thanks @VikingGlen, updated snippet. though I just added to match exact pattern it may not required.

Answer (score 0):

The following I like to think of as "Blue Collar" coding.  It won't win any awards, but it does the job. And it's written so anyone at a glance can look at it and figure out what's going on.  As written, it works on the front end pulling the addresses from the 'file' string.  If you remove the forward slashes from the three lines that are commented out, and change:

```
const address = parseAddressFile('file'); to    
const address = parseAddressFile('addresses.txt');
```

or whatever your text file is named, you can use it on the back end.

The following code assumes that the addresses are formatted correctly.

```js
file = 
`123 Main St.
Nowhere, MN 55414

234 1st St. S.
Not Here, SD 61743

147 Johnson Pkwy
Los Angeles, CA 90217
`;


const parseAddressFile = path => {
//    const fs = require('fs');
//    const file = fs.readFileSync(path).toString('utf-8');
    let address = [], tmp, obj, object = {};
    object = file.matchAll(/^.+$/mg);   // Removes empty lines
    object = Array.from(object);

    for (let key in object) {
        if ( tmp = object[key][0].match(/^(?<streetNumber>\d+) (?<streetName>.*)$/) ) {
            obj = { streetNumber: tmp.groups.streetNumber, streetName: tmp.groups.streetName }
        } else 
        if ( tmp = object[key][0].match(/^(?<city>.*), (?<state>\w.*) (?<postalCode>[\d\-]+)$/) ) {
            obj['city']  = tmp.groups.city, 
            obj['state'] = tmp.groups.state, 
            obj['postalCode']   = tmp.groups.postalCode;
            address.push(obj);
            obj = null;
        } else { console.error('No Match Found') }
    } return address;
}
//const address = parseAddressFile('addresses.txt');
const address = parseAddressFile('file');
console.log(address);
```

The following code assumes that the house number and street address line is correct, but that something is missing from the city, state, or zipcode. It also includes examples of using both unnamed groups (house number and street) and named groups (city, state, zip).

```js
file = 
`123 Main St.
Nowhere, MN

234 1st St. S.
Not Here, 61743

147 Johnson Pkwy
CA 90217
`;

let address, array = [], tmp, obj, object = {};
object = file.matchAll(/^.+$/mg);   // Removes empty lines
object = Array.from(object);
for (let key in object) {
    if (tmp = object[key][0].match( /^(\d+) (.*)$/ ) ) { obj = { houseNumber: tmp[1], streetName: tmp[2] } } else 
    if (tmp = object[key][0].match( /^(?<city>[a-zA-Z\s]{4,})?,? ?(?<state>\w{2})? ?(?<zip>\d{5})?$/ ) ) { 
        (tmp.groups.city)  ? obj['city']  = tmp.groups.city  : obj['city']  = null ; 
        (tmp.groups.state) ? obj['state'] = tmp.groups.state : obj['state'] = null ; 
        (tmp.groups.zip)   ? obj['zip']   = tmp.groups.zip   : obj['zip']   = null ;
        array.push(obj);
        obj = {};
    }
}
console.log(array);
```